# Как правильно реализовать поиск анкет по городу? Технические вопросы

Tags: php, google-maps

Имеется база городов. Общедоступна из интернета, бекап 2014 года из ВК. Вопросов несколько:

1. База старая 2014 года, свежее нет. Есть какие либо апи? Знаю есть у ВК, но с украиной проблемы будут, парсится не будет. Да и надо чтобы к городу был привязан ID. Также знаю у гугл есть сервис Maps, но там даже улицы можно прописать, и часто люди пишут свою улицу. Тот, кто ищет, вводит город, и уже они не найдут друг друга. Возможно ли как-то ограничить ввод данных по улице?
2. Даже сделать по апи гугла, гугл выдаст вариант Moscow. А другой человек, что будет искать, в фильтре гугл ему предложит Москва. И как тут быть?? Они ведь не найдут друг друга. Я сомневаюсь, что гугл привязал города по ID.
3. Есть ли готовое решение по апи, оплата только за запросы?
4. Вдруг, сайт станет мировым, и будет многоязычным. Как города привязать по языку? Например Харьков и Харків.
5. Если делать свою базу, я не смогу 100500 городам менять названия на более свежие, какой выход?

Answer (score 0):

Идентифицировать города можно по IATA кодам. У aviasales можно скачать базу городов с iata, координатами, правда на русском - https://api.travelpayouts.com/data/ru/cities.json

То есть первоначально отталкиваться от нее, а потом искать и другие базы, из которых, например по координатам извлекать названия городов и обновлять свою базу